# Clicking close button on image lightbox doubleclick and force background link to open

Tags: jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I have this problem on woocommerce site, that when user on mobile click close button on image lightbox link in background is also clicked. In my example close button overlap basket icon. So when you close image, basket is opened. [close button is over basket icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ta798.jpg)  I am using wocommerce 3.0 lightbox

link to page with problem: https://nakit-ure.si/rocne-ure/rocna-ura-just-watch-jw20004-008/  (open in mobile view click on image and then try closing it)

I tried using jquery:
1. first add class on basket when image is opened

```
CSS
{
.pointer-disable{pointer-events:none}
}
```

THIS JQUERY WORK

```
(function($) {
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.wp-post-image').click(function(){

$('.nav-right').addClass('pointer-disable');

});
})
})(jQuery);
```

NOW I need to disable class when image is closed.

remove class when image is closed. 
THIS JQUERY DONT work

```
(function($) {
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.pswp__button--close').click(function(){

$('.nav-right').removeClass('pointer-disable');

});
})
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use $('className').on('click') instead of .click() events because the former can use less memory and work for dynamically added elements.

Comment: thank you for advice. I think jquery operations don't apply on .pswp elements. Do you have any other solution how can I check if a image is closed?

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
(function($) {
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.pswp__button--close').click(function(){

$('.pointer-disable').hide();

});
})
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: thank you but didn't work. I think jquery operations don't work on 
.pswp__button--close

Answer (score 0):

You just have to strop the event bubbling:

```
$( ".wp-post-image" )on('click', function( event ) {
  event.stopPropagation();

});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem solved in my case. If I understand correctly, the reason was in event bubbling and capturing. Woocommerce lightbox is a div layer with heigh z-index. But touch event on this layer works also for lower layer. It was need to stop event handling. I used for this ontouchstart = “return false;”, which was added to woocommerce/single-product/photoswipe.php.

```
 <button class="pswp__button pswp__button--close" ontouchstart="return false;"></button>
```